# How can I merge IMAP mailboxes at my old and new ISP?

Tags: email, migration, imap

I have a Mailbox and I get eMails via iMap (not pop). On my old ISP, there is the old Mailbox with folders and emails. I transferred my domain to a new ISP and I have a new mailbox, with all new emails received since the transfer. I check my email via Thunderbird. At the moment I have two email boxes.

Can I get my old emails from the old ISP and have Thunderbird merge the old mails together into the new mailbox? Or can I get Thunderbird to delete some emails?

Comment: Have you tried simply dragging the old emails from that account into a folder in the new account?